# Check value entered by user against a list of options in JS

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, event-listener

Given text input where user could submit answer either by **submit click button** or **Enter key**:

```
</div>
<div class="answer">
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your answer" class="answer_text" id="answer_text_box">
<input type="button" value="Answer"  class="submit_button" id="answer_submit_button">
</div>
```

I want to get the value of text entered by user once the submit their answer, possibly comparing it against a list of items **list_options**.

Here is my working; since I am very new to JS, I thought of writing the value to place holder tag in the html document, then re-reading the html file and getting the value .. it doesn't seem efficient, since I already got the value via **.addEventListener**:

```
<div class="user_answer" id="user_answer_for_js"></div>
```

**Here is my working in JavaScript:**

```
const answer_area = document.getElementById('answer_text_box');
const answer_btn = document.getElementById('answer_submit_button');

let list_options = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];



// Load all events listerns
loadEventListeners();
// Load all events listerns

function loadEventListeners() {
    // Submit answer via submit button:
    answer_btn.addEventListener('click', submitButtonClick);
    // Submit answer via enter key:
    answer_area.addEventListener('keyup', submitEnterKey);
    }


function submitButtonClick(e) {
    let user_answer = answer_area.value;
    document.getElementById("user_answer_for_js").textContent = user_answer.trim();
    console.log(`Submit Via Enter Button: ${user_answer}`);
    e.preventDefault();
}

function submitEnterKey(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            let user_answer = answer_area.value;
            document.getElementById("user_answer_for_js").textContent = user_answer.trim();
            console.log(`Submit Via Enter Key: ${user_answer}`);
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where in the code do you want to compare the entered text value?

Comment: @Mordor1110, the array named: list_options  is the one I want to compare user answer against. But my biggest problem is that I am not able to get value which was got by eventlistener.

Answer (score 1):

**1. For getting the user answer** you have to load your script after the html elements have been loaded. Right now your code is getting a html element that hasn't been loaded yet.

For doing this, place your `<script>` tag right before closing yor `<body>` tag:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  
</div>
<div class="answer">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your answer" class="answer_text" id="answer_text_box">
  <input type="button" value="Answer" class="submit_button" id="answer_submit_button">
</div>

<div class="user_answer" id="user_answer_for_js"></div>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**2. For comparing use [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):**

```
let list_options = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

let user_answer = "January";
list_options.includes(user_answer); # False

user_answer = "Monday";
list_options.includes(user_answer); # True
```

Hope it helps!